# Allow the user to select and copy text in a TTStyledTextLabel

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I'm not sure if this is a [Three20](http://three20.info) question or general ios/iphone (I'm a noob in both areas.)

I'm currently using `TTStyledTextLabel` in a table view to render styled content. Now I would like to allow the user to select text and copy it. Checking the source for `TTSTyledTextLabel` I find this:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIResponderStandardEditActions

- (void)copy:(id)sender {
  NSString* text = _text.rootNode.outerText;
  UIPasteboard* pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  [pasteboard setValue:text forPasteboardType:@"public.utf8-plain-text"];
}
```

Which indicates that the label is ready to help with the actual copying. But I can't figure out how to make it allow for text selection.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I am trying to do exactly same thing as you too, have you figured out how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: No, except that it's probably almost impossible. I've now added quote-buttons in the UI instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this years later... This isn't possible without rewriting the TTStyledText classes substantially.